# Is and As operator in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, operators

I am working on a project from school where I need to use is and as operators. I got this example from school

[image]

The assignment is that I need to find "chip registration" numbers from the object Cat (Cat is derrived from Animal). I don't know how to implement this. At the moment this is what I have:

```
    public void CheckCatHabitsIs(Animal a)
    {
        if (a is Cat)
        {
            Cat c = (Cat)a;

            foreach (var p in c.ChipRegistrationNumber)
            {
                lbShowCatHabits.Items.Add(p);
            }
        }
    }
```

And I want to place this method in a button click event, like so

```
    private void btnShowBadHabits_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CheckCatHabitsIs(/*Need to fill something in here.. but I don't know what*/);


        //foreach (var c in administration.animalList)
        //{
        //    lbShowCatHabits.Items.Add(c);
        //}
    }
```

I am kinda stuck. I don't know if I am heading in the right way. Also I do not know what to place in the method as parameter.

I hope my question makes any sense.

Thanks in advance

Comment: please post the class animal and cat - should be something like CheckCatHabitsIs(new Cat());  you need to pass a animal object into the method. and if you don't have one you need to create one

Comment: CheckCatHabitsIs() is for Cats only (I assume it from method's name)? Then why not change argument's type to Cat?

Comment: What *could* you use as parameter? What kind of input is available? We can't see the bigger picture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update:

Sorry for the trouble. I have found my problem. The solution that I was looking for was this:

```
    private void btnShowBadHabits_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Cat cat = new Cat("", null, "", "Good", (Gender)cbGender.SelectedItem);
        Animal animal = cat;

        if (animal is Cat)
        {
            lbShowCatHabits.Items.Add(cat.BadHabits);
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("No cats found");
        }
```

Probably my explanation was too far away. But thanks for the given reactions :)

ps: I know that my new cat object now always have the same value, but I can change that. That's not the problem